# Access global function from a third party script

Tags: nuxt.js

I am trying to install a script that declares a global function and access it inside some pages.

The script is a "conversion tracking tag" from Google Tag Manager (GTM). It's pretty simple and very similar to lot of third parties script (for analytics or other.)

[GTM's documentation](http://slashdot.org) asks to set up 3 scripts :

1) Script in header

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: 123456789 -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-123456789">
```

2) Initialisation script

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'AW-123456789');
</script>
```

3) Page script

```
<!-- Event snippet for Example conversion page -->
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-123456789/AbC-D_efG-h12_34-567',
    'value': 1.0,
    'currency': 'USD'
  });
</script>
```

---

#### My attempt

1) Script in header

This is very well documented and straightforward. I have edited the `nuxt.config.js` file :

```
//nuxt.config.js

module.exports = {
  head: {
    //...
    link: [
      //...
      {
        src: "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-123456789",
        async: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Looks good, I can see the request in the network connections.

2) Initialisation script

I have created a simple Nuxt plugin :

```
// plugins/gtag.js

/* eslint-disable */
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() {
  dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag("js", new Date());
gtag("config", "AW-123456789");
```

and load it in browser :

```
//nuxt.config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    //...
    { src: "@/plugins/gtag", ssr: false }
  ],
}
```

3) Page script

This is the part I am having troubles.

I want to access the `gtag()` function declare in the plugin from some pages.

So I am calling the script inside a method :

```
methods: {
  open() {
    gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-123456789/AbC-D_efG-h12_34-567',
      'value': 1.0,
      'currency': 'USD'
    });
  }
}
```

I got the error :

> ReferenceError: gtag is not defined

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the function only in the plugin scope.

What you want to do is to **inject** your function into the Vue instance(s) and the SSR context ([docs](https://github.com/nuxt/docs/blob/2.0/en/guide/plugins.md#inject-in-root--context)):

```
// plugins/gtag.js

/* eslint-disable */
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
const gtag = function() {
  dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag("js", new Date());
gtag("config", "AW-123456789");

module.exports = ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('gtag', gtag)
}
```

Use it like this (be aware of the mandatory `$` sign in front of your function):

```
methods: {
  open() {
    this.$gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-123456789/AbC-D_efG-h12_34-567',
      'value': 1.0,
      'currency': 'USD'
    });
  }
}
```